# PHP - Safe division by distributing whole numbers

Tags: php, math

Is there a math functon in PHP that would provide safe division without fractions/decimal numbers? Meaning that it would "distribute" the amount as equally as possible, but only in whole numbers.

Some examples:

`10/3 = [4, 3, 3]`

`11/3 = [4, 4, 3]`

`50/2 = [25, 25]`

`51/2 = [26, 25]`

`40/5 = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]`

`40/3 = [14, 13, 13]`

Meaning that `40/3` should give me three values `14`, `13` and `13`

Comment: Did you try ceil and floor functions?

Comment: What does 10/3 = [4, 3, 3] mean?

Comment: Use a money library: https://github.com/moneyphp/money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no working solution yet, here's one:

The question seems to ask to split (partition) an integer number `s` into a set of `n` numbers that are either `q1 = ceil(s/n)` or `q2 = floor(s/n)`
Since `q1 - q2 = 1`, that split can be generated by the formula:

```
q1 * (s - q2 * n) + q2 * (q1 * n - s) = (q1 - q2) * s = s,
```

that is

```
s = n1 * q1 + n2 * q2,
```

with `n1 = s - q2 * n`,  `n2 = q1 * n - s`, and `n1 + n2  = (q1 - q2) * n = n`

Php function:

```php
function splitInt($s, $n) {
  $q = $s / $n;
  $q1 = ceil($q);
  $q2 = floor($q);
  $n1 =  $q1 * $n - $s;
  // the result is [$n1 x q1, ($n - $n1) x $q2]
  return array_pad(array_fill(0, $n1, $q1), $n, $q2);
}
```

Example:

```php
$res = splitInt(100, 7);
echo json_encode($res) . "\n";
$sum = array_sum($res);
$count = count($res);
echo "count = $count   sum = $sum\n\n";
```

gives

```
[15,15,14,14,14,14,14]
count = 7   sum = 100
```

More examples in [sandbox](https://onecompiler.com/php/3zcandr7z).

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing out of stock. You may write your own function for it.

```php
function sdiv(int $dividend, int $divisor): array {
  $q = (int) floor($dividend / $divisor);
  $r = $dividend % $divisor;
  return array_merge(
    array_fill(0, $r, $q + 1),
    array_fill(0, $divisor - $r, $q),
  );
}

assert(sdiv(10, 3) === [4, 3, 3]);
assert(sdiv(11, 3) === [4, 4, 3]);
assert(sdiv(15, 4) === [4, 4, 4, 3]);
assert(sdiv(16, 4) === [4, 4, 4, 4]);
assert(sdiv(17, 4) === [5, 4, 4, 4]);
assert(sdiv(18, 4) === [5, 5, 4, 4]);
```

Run this with `php -d zend.assertions=1 filename.php` and all assertion should pass.

Comment: This will not work when there are four answers.  Please fix if you want my vote

Comment: The original post was very unclear about what "safe division" means. My old answer fit the then demonstrated input and output. I've updated my answer to fit the updated question.